# Bootstrap navbar-toggleable-md se activa en el pixel 991: ¿puedo hacer que se active en el 1100?

Tags: bootstrap

```html
<header class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light  fixed-top mediumnavigation">
```

Esta sentencia es con la que bootstrap hace mi menú responsive. He probado con `navbar-toggleable-lg` pero necesito algo intermedio.

¿Cómo puedo hacer que `navbar-toggleable-md` se active en el pixel 1100 y no en el 991?

He buscado en los css de bootstrap y no encuentro `navbar-toggleable-md` para cambiarle el media query.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Con qué versión de Bootstrap estás trabajando? No olvides colocarlo en las etiquetas.

Comment: https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css

Comment: Solución _más o menos_ corta pero implica recompilar el css: modificar el SCSS (__variables.scss_) en donde aparece la variable `$grid-breakpoints`, la cual es referenciada en __navbar.scss_. Solución corta pero que implica tener que modificar varias clases en el css: trabajar con el `@media (min-width: 992px)` donde aparece `navbar-toggleable-md`. Por cierto, desde la versión beta de Bootstrap 4, `navbar-toggleable` es reemplazado por `navbar-expand`.